# how to save multiple images in table using laravel php

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hi please help me am new to laravel
I want to store multiple images in table... With this code am unable to     save.

Help me for this..

Here in my View

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'businessdirectory/business', 'files'=>true))}}
{{Form::label('image','Upload Image')}}

<div class="form-group">{{Form::file('image[]',array('multiple'=>true))}} 

</div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

In my Controller

```
 if(Input::file('image'))
        {
        $image = Input::file('image');

        foreach($image as $img) {
        $destination = 'images';
        $filename = $img->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = 'images/'.$filename;
        $uploadSuccess = $img->move($destination,$filename);
        }
        }
        else
        {
            $path='images/default.JPG';
        }
 $business = new Business();    
 $business->image = $path;
```

Comment: There is no need to use the quote operator (`>`) to render the question in a quote block; an edit will shortly be approved to fix that.

Comment: Also, some code lines are not in the code block!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not advisable to store images on database. Just save the path of the images instead.

If you really need to store image on db. Make sure you set the column to blob as it need more space. Then, get the image content and type, then save it.

```
<?php
$image = fopen($image_path, 'rb');
// or
$image = file_get_contents($image_path);

$business = new Business;
$business->image = $image;
$business->imageType = "image/gif"; // 
$business->save();

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks You very much for reply and Yes I want to save the paths only...! mulltiple image paths.. With My code am saving only one path..

Answer (score -1):

You need to put below code inside the foreach loop. In every loop you need to insert image path inside a database

```
 $business = new Business();    
 $business->image = $path;
```

This is a working code in laravel 5.2.

```
$files = $request->file('file');
 if($request->hasfile('file')){ 
    $destinationPath = 'uploads';
    foreach($files as $file){
        $image = new Image;
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->name = $filename;
        $image->save(); 
        $file->move($destinationPath,$filename);
    }
```