# laravel won't save multiple filename of image to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

so this is my sotre controller

```
$images = $request->file('image');
$file_count = count($images);
$uploadcount = 0;
$daily = new Report();

foreach($images as $image) {    
    $daily = new Report();    
    $destination ='img/report';
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    storage::put('img/report/'.$filename,file_get_contents($image->getRealPath()));        
    $daily->image = $filename;
    $uploadcount ++;        
}
$daily->author = $request->author;
$daily->desc = $request->desc;
// $daily->created_at = Carbon::now();
$daily->save();
if($uploadcount == $file_count){ 
    return redirect('/daily');
}else{
    return redirect('/daily/create');
}
```

and this is my Blade :

```
    <form action="/daily/create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}">
    {{-- date --}}
    {!! Form::text('date', old('date', Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('d-m-Y')),['class'=>'form-control date-picker']) !!}
    {{-- penulis --}}
    <label for="author">Author :</label>
    <input  name="author" type="text" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
    {{-- textarea --}}
    <label for="desc">Description</label>
    <textarea name="desc" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    {{-- input image --}}
    <div class="file-field input-field">
  <div class="btn">
    <span>File</span>
    <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple>
  </div>
  <div class="file-path-wrapper">
    <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files">
  </div>
</div>
<center>
<input type="submit" class="btn">
</center>

    </form>
```

all images has been add and saved to folder, but i just get the last image name..
i read this post [how to save multiple images in table using laravel php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719584/how-to-save-multiple-images-in-table-using-laravel-php) many time
and still didn't know how to fix it hellppppppp...

Comment: but you successfully save 1 data?

Comment: @NewbeeDev yes, if i store one more data, i just get the last image 'name'
that mean
image: 1.jpg, 2.jpg | all this image has been save to database 
name: 2.jpg | i just get the last image 'name'

Comment: Try moving the `$daily->save();` inside the loop. Then it will save all of the files not just the last one

Comment: ah its because you putted your `->save()` function outside loop

Comment: Some simple code indentation make that OBVIOUS

Comment: this code must be inside loop https://gyazo.com/5619470a89861157e3e49280de500378, since you are creating one object alone. you are not doing a saveMany function

Comment: @NewbeeDev Why are you posting off site links in comments as answers. Write an answer if you belive you have solved the issue for the OP

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is obvious, you are able only to save 1 data because you are not saving each 
`new Report()`  inside the foreach loop

What you did is you save it after the loop is finish which is the only save data is last `new Report()` you created inside the foreach loop

To solve that place it place this code

```
$daily->author = $request->author;
$daily->desc = $request->desc;
// $daily->created_at = Carbon::now();
$daily->save();
```

inside foreach loop

```
$images = $request->file('image');
$file_count = count($images);
$uploadcount = 0;

foreach($images as $image) {    
    $daily = new Report();    
    $destination ='img/report';
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    storage::put('img/report/'.$filename,file_get_contents($image->getRealPath()));        
    $daily->image = $filename;
    $uploadcount ++;

    $daily->author = $request->author;
    $daily->desc = $request->desc;
    // $daily->created_at = Carbon::now();
    $daily->save();     
}
if($uploadcount == $file_count){ 
    return redirect('/daily');
}else{
    return redirect('/daily/create');
}
```

Comment: Thats better, now you can get rep for it as well +1

Comment: And the OP might even accept it as the correct answer, if you are lucky

Comment: the output in database table:
name : image 
name : image
and i want make it like this :
name, name : image, image

Comment: @haikalhikmi lets continue here.
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130450/laravel-wont-save-multiple-filename-of-image-to-database